# I have video recorded at 30fps but Vegas rendered at 29.97 fps? What difference would it create for uploading to YouTube? Advantages/Disadvantage?

Tags: youtube, frame-rate

I have video recorded at 30fps but Vegas rendered at 29.97 fps? What difference would it create for uploading to YouTube? What would be the advantages or disadvantages of the same?

Comment: Are you sure it's recorded at exactly 30Hz? 29.97 is the normal NTSC frequency.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, I recorded the video using an app on my smartphone. I saw the option on smartphone as 30fps